# How to do Backward/forward Data grouping in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum, pandas-groupby

There are different types of group level available in the actual data set, We would be required different types of group-wise report. (Note: group wise report is not simple hence please read below example carefully)

**Requirement Example**

when we need to report 4th level group report then need to sum data field till the last value before 4th level. The report number might any number given in the "Group" column. **(Kindly refer Expected output for more clarity)**

For Rest of the filed, treatment as below:

**purchase_date, Info1 & Info2:** Pickup date available at the group level

**data** : Sum

**Actual Database:**

```
Group   purchase_date   Info1   Info2   data
2       03/23/2019      A       B       57
3       03/24/2019      A       B       48
4       03/25/2019      A       B       40
1       03/26/2019      Q       B       60
2       03/27/2019      Q       B       42
3       03/28/2019      Q       B       33
4       03/29/2019      Q       B       36
1       03/30/2019      R       B       54
2       03/31/2019      R       B       57
3       04/01/2019      R       B       53
4       04/02/2019      R       B       56
1       04/03/2019      A       B       48
2       04/04/2019      A       B       40
3       04/05/2019      A       B       45
4       04/06/2019      A       B       60
1       04/07/2019      A       B       38
2       04/08/2019      A       B       58
```

Expected output after grouping data as per the above requirement:

```
4th group level report:             
Group   purchase_date   Info1   Info2   data
4       03/25/2019      A       B       145
4       03/29/2019      Q       B       171
4       04/02/2019      R       B       220
4       04/06/2019      A       B       193
4       04/08/2019      A       B       96

2nd group level Report
Group   purchase_date   Info1   Info2   data
2       03/23/2019      A       B       57
2       03/27/2019      Q       B       190
2       03/31/2019      R       B       180
2       04/04/2019      A       B       197
2       04/08/2019      A       B       201
```

I have tried it with group by function but I am not able to Kick-off it.

Can anyone help me to get the desired output?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each part of the question just refers me to some other part of the question. This isn't clear at all without me piecing together what changed between the dfs

Comment: Ok , I read it carefully :-)  and what did you try ?

Comment: @roganjosh, but all part is redirecting the towared expected output, here I have given the example of backward grouping for the different data value available in "Group" Column.

Comment: @Wen-Ben, I have tried "Pandas group by" but it only allows me to do simple aggregation only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following function `f(z, l)` with parameter `l` being the required level and `z` being your DataFrame:

```
def f(z, l):
    x = (z['Group'] == l) | (z.index == z.index[-1])
    cs = z['data'].cumsum()
    dx = cs - cs.where(x, np.nan).ffill().shift(1).fillna(0)
    return z[x].drop('data', 1).assign(Group=l).join(dx)

print(f(df, 2))
print(f(df, 4))
```

Output:

```
    Group purchase_date Info1 Info2   data
0       2    03/23/2019     A     B   57.0
4       2    03/27/2019     Q     B  190.0
8       2    03/31/2019     R     B  180.0
12      2    04/04/2019     A     B  197.0
16      2    04/08/2019     A     B  201.0


    Group purchase_date Info1 Info2   data
2       4    03/25/2019     A     B  145.0
6       4    03/29/2019     Q     B  171.0
10      4    04/02/2019     R     B  220.0
14      4    04/06/2019     A     B  193.0
16      4    04/08/2019     A     B   96.0
```

It basically calculates cumulative sums with `cumsum` resetting them every time we hit a record with the given level or the last record in the DataFrame.

**Update:** to make the last row in `purchase_date` always equal to previous row + 4 days:

```
def f(z, l):
    x = (z['Group'] == l) | (z.index == z.index[-1])
    cs = z['data'].cumsum()
    dx = cs - cs.where(x, np.nan).ffill().shift(1).fillna(0)
    zz = z[x].drop('data', 1).assign(Group=l).join(dx)
    zz['purchase_date'] = pd.to_datetime(zz['purchase_date'])
    zz.at[zz.index[-1], 'purchase_date'] = zz.at[zz.index[-2], 'purchase_date'] + pd.Timedelta('4d')
    return zz
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. is it possible to maintain the gap in the last row "purchase_date"? There is 4-days gap in the "purchase_date" column that I also need in the last row as well.

Comment: Is it always going to be next to last value + 4 days or do you need to somehow derive this dynamically?

Comment: I think that will not work because you are using index[-2] hence it will refer second last row of df but we haven't reset Index yet, is there any other workaround?

Comment: You're right, of course. I think the easiest is to save the result that we're going to return as a new DataFrame `zz` and then do the adjustment. Please see Update section of my answer